# How to find all dependencies of a .NET project?

Tags: .net, dependencies

Basically, what I need is something like [Dependecy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), but it should work with .NET applications. Is there anywhere such tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) - previously from Lutz Roeder, now from Red-Gate software.

Answer (score 10):

For .NET 4, check our CheckAsm: http://www.amberfish.net/

Comment: After dependency walker failed to help me (does not show any .net assemblies referenced by the target library), I searched for a specific .net dependency app and this did the trick. Easy to read and will discover and alert if there are circular dependencies.

Comment: Works as advertised. Only shows managed dependencies (is it even possible to automatically show unmanaged dependencies of a managed app?) Free version only shows hierarchy, not graphs. (Make sure to hit Decline during free version install to avoid getting add-on wares.)

Comment: I don't know if this changed recently but the unpaid installer installs unwanted crapware like a "registry cleaner" and "search protect" I would avoid installing this program!

Answer (score 9):

I prefer [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net). It's an open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler. And yes, it shows dependencies.

Decent replacement for [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) which is not free anymore.

Answer (score 5):

NDepend is the .NET tool specialized in dependencies management and visualization. 
The tool proposes both a [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) and a [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx). A free trial of the tool is available [here](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx). Here are 2 screenshots of the dependency graph followed by the dependency matrix:

[image: NDepend dependency graph]
[image: NDepend dependency matrix]

Answer (score 2):

During runtime [Systernals](http://www.systernals.com)' [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) might be helpful to see an assemblys dependencies.

Also [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can show you the dependencies and how tightly your components are coupled.

Answer (score 2):

[`ildasm.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) works for this purpose as well.

> This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt (or the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Windows 7).

`ildasm.exe` lists a tree of namespaces, types, methods, etc. on loading an assembly.

[image: IL DASM]

And you can **view all dependencies of the assembly by double clicking *MANIFEST*, and searching for lines starting with `.assembly extern`**.

[image: IL DASM MANIFEST]

`ildasm.exe` comes with Visual Studio or .NET SDK installations, so chances are you've got it on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector is not free and the other one is not free either, just a trial. I had the same problem and found this EXCELLENT tool:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246858/Depends4Net-Part-1

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Walker will work with .Net too.

> the .Net layer still needs to call
>   down to the core Windows functions
>   like LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to
>   do the actual work.  It is at this
>   core level that Dependency Walker
>   understands what is going on.  So,
>   while Dependency Walker may not
>   understand all the language specific
>   complexities of your application, it
>   will still be able to track all module
>   activity at a core Windows API level.

[Reference](http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html)

Comment: I think this is not correct.  It will detect the dependencies to native assemblies, yes, but it will not detect/see dependencies to .NET assemblies.  For example, it will show a dependency to, say, kernel32.dll, but it won't show dependencies to, say, System.ServiceModel.dll. Can you elaborate?