# How can I draw a graph of references between projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I want to see in a graphical way the dependencies between my projects in my solution.
Is there any Visual Studio internal or external tool that can help me?

There is a similar post at
[How to find all dependencies of a .NET project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197447/how-to-find-all-dependencies-of-a-net-project)

But I am more interested in the graphical aspect.

Comment: Any luck with VS2010 gallery?? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197447/how-to-find-all-dependencies-of-a-net-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) does that.

[image]

Comment: and here you'll find documentation about NDepend graph http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx