# InnoSetup detecting dependencies for .NET project

Tags: .net, inno-setup

Is there a way to detect and add to an innosetup script the dependencies of a >NET executable? Let's say I have a.exe and b.dll. c.dll in my solution, because a.exe is using those dlls. Is there a tool that can look at the executable and add b.dll and c.dll to the script as files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the dependencies of a .NET app are the DLLs that VS already copied into the output folder, plus the framework itself.  So it's easy to catch all non-framework dependencies with a simple:

```
[Files]
Source: bin\Release\MyApp.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: bin\Release\*.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Typically you don't need anything more complex unless you also depend on native or COM libraries, which don't get copied automatically -- but you should already know what those are.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool for this in Inno Setup - it looks more like programming job (C#...) than Inno scripting.

Maybe there is some (3rd party) extension which can do this?
For example see this topic: [How to find all dependencies of a .NET project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197447/how-to-find-all-dependencies-of-a-net-project)

Reflector (also Dependency Walker) works on compiled .exe file but you need to do this on the fly so this is my idea:

Create simple tool which loads your **.csproj** file and read the *References* node.

References are saved as this (CRefDll is C language project, dotNetDll is .net Library) :

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\CRefDll\CRefDll.vcxproj">
  <Project>{26BB3110-CF72-4A1A-B1AC-1ADA0CCE41C4}</Project>
  <Name>CRefDll</Name>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\dotNetDll\dotNetDll.csproj">
  <Project>{14A56846-4ADA-421D-9F49-380CA20A7A63}</Project>
  <Name>dotNetDll</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

So the tool should load all elements in this node (files **CRefDll.vcxproj** and **dotNetDll.csproj**) and simply get correct output (with path) from them (using dotNetDll sometimes is not enough).

If I misunderstood your question and you need to detect and install .net Framework from Inno Setup it is not problem (and it is pretty easy) but your description look little different.